# How to sort and fetch the builds in Artifactory using curl/wget

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-pipelines

I have around 50 builds in Artifactory.
How do I download the latest one? i.e. which is created last

```
curl -u username:password --silent https://artifactory.mas.emrsn.org/artifactory/pme-modernization/ModuleBuilder/develop/ -d items.find({"repo":"develop"}).sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(1)
```

```
curl -u username:password -X POST https://artifactory.mas.emrsn.org/artifactory/pme-modernization/ModuleBuilder/develop/api/search/aql -H "content-type: text/plain" -d items.find({"repo":"develop"},{"name":{$match":"*.zip"}})
```